Rails 7.2 - unexpected behaviour with duration and postgres interval type
I'm upgrading a Rails app from 7.1.3.4 to 7.2 and I'm quite stumped by a new behaviour.
We have an object analagous to:
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :set_duration
  before_save :update_classification

  def set_duration
    self.duration = end_datetime - start_datetime
  end

  def update_classification
    if duration >= 4.hours 
      self.classification = "long"
    else
      self.classification = "short"
    end
  end
end

and tests like:
class EventTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @event = build(:event)
  end

  test "duration and classification are updated correctly before_save" do
    @event.start_datetime = Time.now.utc
    @event.end_datetime = 6.hours.from_now.utc

    @event.save!
    assert_equal "Long", @event.classification
    assert_equal 6.hours, @event.duration.round
  end
end

In Rails 7.1.3.4, this passed. Following the 7.2 upgrade, it fails on the last line: NoMethodError: undefined method `round' for nil. Using debugger, I can see that duration and classification are both nil before the save! call, but afterwards only classification has a value. If I call @event.reload after the save, then the duration value loads correctly! In the console, a save call produces SQL like:
Event Create (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "Events" ("created_at", "updated_at", "start_datetime", "end_datetime", "duration", "classification") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2024-10-17 20:51:14.844042"], ["updated_at", "2024-10-17 20:51:14.844042"], ["start_datetime", "2024-10-17 20:50:56.515026"], ["end_datetime", "2024-10-18 02:50:55.377912"], ["classification", "Long"], ["duration", "PT5H59M58.86288599999898S"]]

We're using Postgres and the schema looks something like:
  create_table "impairments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.datetime "start_datetime"
    t.datetime "end_datetime"
    t.string "classification"
    t.interval "duration"
  end

So, what am I missing? I notice in the 7.2 release notes, it says: Remove deprecated support to quote ActiveSupport::Duration. Am I right in guessing it's something to do with this? Is there an obvious or easy way to solve the issue? I can refactor many tests and production code with reload statements, but that's not ideal, and I suspect I'm missing something elementary.

Just my guess. Try adding something like this
attribute :duration, :interval or
attribute :duration, :string
More about this:
https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-1-adds-postgresql-interval-data-type

A suggestion: don't store the duration. Calculate it from start_datetime and end_datetime as needed, or add a generated column. Then you don't need this code. Also consider using a single tstzrange column.

Interesting - thanks for the suggestions! We chose to store it because searching and sorting by duration is very common; calculating as needed was our first approach but was getting cumbersome. Will look into generated columns, and tstzrange looks very promising. I'll need to learn a bit about how to work validations etc on these as we actually do more complex logic with the start and end dates, but appreaciate the pointer towards them.

The solution was remarkably easy. Adding .to_i on the set_duration call solved it - apparently passing an int to postgres instead of a float makes all the difference!
  def set_duration
    self.duration = (end_datetime - start_datetime).to_i
  end

It's still not totally clear to me why Rails 7.2 broke the previous functionality, but a quick solution like this is a win.
